# Not getting the data form json file in chrome net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

Not getting the data in chrome in firefox works fine. Need to work offline and online also. That should fetch data form json but not woking in chrome.

```
$.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: "filename.json",
      dataType: "text",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);

      }
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: That return won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Can you please show the url? Is this running on a server or a simple html file?

Comment: is `JSONFile` a previous defined varialbe? If not, then correct the `url`

Comment: JSONFile is already declared variable var JSONFile ="filename.json"

Comment: Be sure to run a web server. Ajax fails in local.